# Mysql multiple selects & joins

Tags: mysql, join, multiple-tables

I have this query:

```
SELECT suppliers.*, porders.om_quote_no, orders.project_ref 
FROM suppliers, porders, orders 
WHERE suppliers.supp_short_code = suppliers.supp_short_code
```

`porders` is a table with `supp_short_code` and `om_quote_no`, `orders` is a table with `supp_short_code` and `project_ref`, `suppliers` has all of the details include a `supp_short_code` column. I'm trying to get to a point where someone can see one `supp_short_code` and see what orders were placed against it. Ie. `supp_short_code` being the common column in each table!

Is this possible...?

Comment: What exactly do the different tables represent, and how do they relate to each other?

Comment: the relate by the supp_short_code is the common key between them. porders is an archived table of purchase orders, orders is a table of current purchase orders, suppliers is the table with all of the suppliers details. So i'm trying to display all purchase orders grouped by supp_short_code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT s.*,p.om_quote_no,o.project_ref FROM 
orders AS ord,porders AS p,suppliers AS s WHERE o.supp_short_code = p.supp_short_code AND      o.supp_short_code = s.supp_short_code
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if I get your problem right. Especially your WHERE clause confuses me.

How about this one:

```
SELECT 
s.*,
p.om_quote_no,
o.project_ref
FROM
orders o
INNER JOIN porders p ON o.supp_short_code = p.supp_short_code
INNER JOIN suppliers s ON o.supp_short_code = s.supp_short_code
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it makes more sense to do two separate select statements:

```
SELECT suppliers.*, porders.om_quote_no
FROM suppliers, porders
WHERE suppliers.supp_short_code = porders.supp_short_code

SELECT suppliers.*, orders.project_ref 
FROM suppliers, orders 
WHERE suppliers.supp_short_code = orders.supp_short_code
```

If `porders.om_quote_no` and `orders.project_ref` are of the same type, you can merge the two results with a UNION.